# Redirection from HTTP to HTTPS in CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a CloudFront distribution for the static website, but my website does not work on http anymore. It works fine with S3 endpoint, but gives a blank page on CloudFront endpoint and my website. Check the images for reference.

[image: iamge1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Can you provide exact details of your CF disto setup?

Comment: I have added images in the answer, if that can help you get the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced similar issue where my https://url.com was giving me blank page. In my case I have made few changes in my distribution which helped me to resolve the issue:

- I have removed the index.html as the root object as my code did not
  have index.html reflecting to anything.
- I have also changed my allowed methods from just GET & HEAD to
  GET,HEAD,OPTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 problem areas:

1. DNS :- Check if its pointed to correctly to cloudfront distribution.
2. S3:- Make sure there's GetObject allowed either to everyone or Cloudfront user (if you plan to restrict content via cloudfront)
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
   "Sid": "AddPerm",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXX/*"
   }
   ]
   }
3. Some wierdo issue with your project files or Cloudfront cache.
   Try invalidating cloudfront cache or upload the project on a new bucket.